# Define "subtle put down"

Tags: support

*Explanation removed to make the question more clear...*

I might not have understood what a subtle put-down is.

Can you please explain what a subtle put-down is in Stack Overflow terms; for dummies like me?

Comment: At least the person who answered "Yes it's possible" actually answered the question directly. The person who posted an answer included a bunch of stuff that wasn't asked for by explaining how to make it happen, beating around the bush just to say that it is possible instead of responding directly to the simple "Is it possible" question the OP was asking.

Comment: I like Shog9's answer but as an explanation  of the Google Doc example, “*You could Google this in 5 seconds”*, is basically calling someone lazy without using the word "lazy".

Comment: @BSMP I doubt that many such questions are from lazy users.  Some are merely optimizing their own time:  why Google yourself if some naive mark on SO will do all the searching and filtering for you?   Others want a unique answer written for them because the other students have already copypasted the Google results.   That is not laziness, merely selfish and uncaring abuse of other SO users.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) applies here, I think... That may well be just a very poor answer.

Comments have and will be deleted at the drop of a hat. If you raise a flag and a comment [doesn't seem to be contributing anything useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237982#237982), the moderator handling it will likely take you at your word that it's problematic in some way and remove it.

Answers... Well, an awful lot of people are just bad at answering. Doesn't mean they're being hurtful, just means they didn't understand the question, don't understand the problem, got distracted part way through writing by a coconut falling on their head, etc. If you're flagging an answer, try to describe in detail *why* the answer is problematic; don't assume the moderator handling the flag will see what you saw.

Your flag - "subtle put down" - didn't explain *why* you felt the answer was problematic. Note that you spent an entire paragraph on it here:

> The answer doesn't try at all to be helpful. It's basically the same as the comment I flagged above, just with more code. But it's saying not more as "Yes it's possible, do it". It's quite sarcastic.

That's 200 characters of explanation vs. 15; that's a LOT more context, a LOT more explanation for why you felt the answer was problematic. A moderator may still disagree, but now they have something to disagree *with* - they have to decide if the answer is indeed sarcastic, unhelpful, dismissive of the asker's problem.

The thing about a subtle put-down is... It's **subtle**. It's a put-down that you can overlook unless, maybe, it's directed at you. An insult with [plausible deniability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability).

Note that this also allows for folks to see insults where none exist; I used to think Indians were being incredibly patronizing toward me on forums because they would persistently address me as "Dear" - in the US, this is almost always sarcastic when used between strangers, but in India it was taught as a formal way of addressing others. These sorts of cultural and language issues make identifying and handling subtle put-downs extremely challenging on a multinational site such as Stack Overflow, and make it all the more important that you be *explicit* about what problems you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that already. I've been asking for _Can you please explain what a subtle put-down is in StackOverflow terms; for dummies like me?_ English isn't my first language, maybe I didn't explain well enough what I was asking in my question... It's not about why a flag got declined...

Comment: ... The only answer so far came from Hans,telling me to ask my mother... :-)

Comment: See my edit, @bambam. You put your explanation here, on meta, instead of in the flag, where it may've done some good.

Comment: Right, thanks. I've been a bit uncertain about the discrepancy between the mods answer _flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention_ and _we take reports seriously_ from the CoC, but I see that the answer was not clearly insulting enough to be understood as insulting without context..

Comment: Apart from that, would you say that the comment wouldn't have been deleted if Hanlon's razor didn't apply here? Would that comment still be ok? I'm just asking because I actually posted such comments before and want to know what you mods/SO thinks is ok... Maybe my answer to the CoC thread shades some more light to why I asked that question.. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct/312163#312163

Comment: Argh! I also have been using "Dear" all the time. Now I wonder how many of my users felt uncomfortable...

Comment: I don't think that comment was helpful, @bambam.

Comment: So I’d be punished for posting it?

Comment: it would be deleted if flagged. Punishment tends to go along with persistently flaunting standards.

Comment: @Shog9: "*An insult with plausible deniability.*" That is probably the most precise explanation for the kind of things we're talking about I've read.

Answer (score 0):

While I admit it's quite vague, and at the discretion of the moderator, I interpret it like this:

> Do not discourage members asking a question or making a statement that could reasonably be useful for someone else.

On the other hand, if you notice that you are tempted to "put-down" the question/statement for it being malicious (say, trying to waste people's time, or get them to do OP's job), you should flag it instead.